# How to query if the time is stored as varchar?

Tags: mysql, time

The time is stored in the database as '09:21 am'

Now how can i get the range result

for instance

```
select * from tablename where stored_time between '09:21 am' and '10:05 pm';
```

I tried the above query but it's not giving the result properly. this is because the time is stored as varchar.

is there any function to convert this string to time and query it in mysql?

Answer (score 5):

Using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) with the following format:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(UPPER('09:21 am'), '%h:%i %p');
/* 09:21:00 */
```

`%h` = Hours 00-12

`%i` = Minutes

`%p` = AM/PM (`UPPER()` converts to uppercase so it matches your lowercase version)

So the full query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 
  /* Use 24h time for the comparison values and wrap stored_time in the STR_TO_DATE() */
  STR_TO_DATE(UPPER(stored_time)) between '09:21:00' and '22:05:00';
```

It is recommended that you switch this column to a real `TIME` or `DATETIME` type rather than storing the value as a string.

Comment: yes i know it will slowdown the process time. but the database i got time stored as string. Anyhow your help made my day..

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` seems to parse lowercase `am/pm` too.

Comment: @agurchand It isn't just the speed (though that is a major factor since indexing doesn't work properly), it's also the inconvenience of having to convert types in order to make use of all the available date/time comparison ad manipulation functions MySQL has.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`. [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
select * from tablename where DATE_FORMAT(stored_time,'%h:%i %p') between 
       DATE_FORMAT('09:21 am','%h:%i %p') and DATE_FORMAT('10:05 pm','%h:%i %p');
```